# regex replace SMT connector a json object to string

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

consider a msg on kafka topic,  `event: { "x":1, "y":2, "c": "abc"}`. I would like to convert the event object to `event: "{\"x\": 1, \"y\":2, \"c\":\"abc\"}`.
Looking to use a regex transformation to capture everything between the curly brace.
Apparently I get an error `Invalid value "{.*?}" for configuration regex: Invalid regex: Illegal repetition near index 0 "{.*?}"`.
Not sure how to solve this.
This is the connector config so far:

```
transforms=escapeBrace
transforms.escapeBrace.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.escapeBrace.regex="\{.*?\}"
transforms.escapeBrace.replacement="\"$1\""
```

Comment: Try to use "\{.*\}"

Comment: `Invalid value "{.*}" for configuration regex: Invalid regex: Illegal repetition near index 0
"{.*}"
^`

Answer (score 0):

`RegexRouter` is only for modifying the **topic name**, not the data within any record. (Topic names cannot contain braces, slashes, or quotes.)

You'll want to try using Kafka Streams, or some other consumer to modify the data before sending to a new topic. Writing your own SMT is another option.